# How to configure setup.py to run tox for test step?

Tags: python, tox

How do I need to configure `setup.py` to run [`tox`](http://tox.testrun.org/latest/) for `test` step?

Answer (score 1):

As the http link is dead in hpk42's link here is an answer:

You can override the test command to run the tox tests instead like so

```
class ToxTest(TestCommand):
    user_options = []

    def initialize_options(self):
        TestCommand.initialize_options(self)

    def run_tests(self):
        import tox
        tox.cmdline()


setuptools.setup(
    name='package',
    version=0.1,
    author='Author',
    author_email='author@gmail.com',
    description='',
    license='GPLv3',
    keywords='',
    url='',
    install_requires=['numpy'],
    packages=[],
    cmdclass = {'test': ToxTest},
)
```